# Bayesian Survival function

Tags: bayesian, pymc

I have managed to estimate the posterior of the latent variables of my model which can be stated as follows (adapted from https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/bayes_param_survival_pymc3.html):
\begin{align}
y_i &= \beta^T x_i + \xi_i\\
\end{align}
where $y_i\equiv \log T_i$, is the log duration and,
\begin{align}
\xi_i &\sim Gumbel(0, s) \\
s &\sim HalfNormal(5)
\end{align}
Note that this can be equivalently stated that $y_i\sim Gumbel(\beta^T x_i, s)$.

Therefore, the likelihood of the dataset for both censored and uncensored data is:
\begin{align}
\log p\left(\cup_{i=1}^N y_i|\beta, s\right) = \sum_{i \in uncensored} \log p\left(y_i=\log T_i|\beta, s\right) + \sum_{i \in censored} \log p\left(y_i>\log T_i|\beta, s\right)
\end{align}

**The question is regarding getting a Bayesian estimate of the survival function**. The author of the above notebook, samples from the posterior predictive distribution of y using:

```
X_.set_value(np.array(x_test)[None,:])
cens_.set_value(np.array([False]))
Y_.set_value(np.zeros(1))
with weibull_model:
    post_trace = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace, vars=[y_obs])
```

and uses the samples of $y$ (converted back to time domain) to generate the survival function with the following logic (for time steps 1 to 200):

```
for t in range(1, 201):
    frac = sum(t_samples > t) / len(t_samples)
    survival_func[t] = frac
```

It makes logical sense to state that the fraction of samples greater than a particular time is the survival rate. However, this is a point estimate of the survival function.

There's two ways I can think of getting a 'Bayesian' estimate of the Survival Function:

1. Sample N number of traces (with say 1000 points) of the posterior predictive distribution and do:

```
for n in range(N):
    for t in range(1, 201):
        frac = sum(t_samples[n] > t) / len(t_samples[n])
        survival_func[N, t] = frac
```

2. We know the CDF of the gumbel distribution *given the latent variables* to be, $\exp\left(-\exp\left(\left(\log T_i - X_i^T\beta\right)/s\right)\right)$. Hence we can let the j-th sample for the survival function for a given value of T to be $1 - \exp\left(-\exp\left(\left(\log T_i - X_i^T\beta^{(j)}\right)/s^{(j)}\right)\right)$ where $\beta^{(j)}, s^{(j)}$ are the samples from the posterior of the latent variables.

Are the two methods equivalent? If not which method is the more correct way of getting a Bayesian sample of the Survival Function.